# memset with 0 and 0X00

Tags: c++, memset

Is there any difference in the below lines:

```
char myname[512]; -- created a character array and wants to memset it.
```

Is there any difference in the below two lines.

```
memset (&myname, 0x00, sizeof(myname));
memset (&myname, 0, sizeof(myname));
```

I am pretty sure that both will nullify the myname array.

Comment: No, there is no difference.

Comment: `0` is `0`, regardless of the base.

Comment: In fact, technically `0` is parsed as an octal constant, not a decimal constant.

Comment: Also, you might want to make sure `sizeof(myname)` is giving you the value you want...

Comment: Or simply write `char myname[512]={};` or use `std::fill`, which will also work when you decide to initialize to something other than `0` with a type that isn't `char`. The nasty thing about `memset` is that it _looks like_ it works when in fact it only "works" by coincidence, in a single special case.

Comment: "0x" is the prefix for a hexadecimal number. "0x00" is the hexadecimal number 00. So 0x00==0x0==0.

Answer (score 2):

The `0x00` syntax is for the programmer only. There will be no difference in the compiled code.

I you want to try the experiment yourself quickly you could use [gcc explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/).

You would see that the generated assembly is identical.